# Unable to toggle editor style after manually editing xcdatamodel/content file

Tags: xcode, core-data

After manually editing the xcdatamodel/content due to a merge conflict I'm able to open and run the project just fine, but I'm unable to toggle the toggle the editor style to show the "object relations diagram"

I'm using Xcode 13.4.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<model type="com.apple.IDECoreDataModeler.DataModel" documentVersion="1.0" lastSavedToolsVersion="21279" systemVersion="21G115" minimumToolsVersion="Automatic" sourceLanguage="Swift" userDefinedModelVersionIdentifier="">
    <entity name="Foo" representedClassName=".foo" syncable="YES">
      ...
    </entity>
    <entity name="Bar" representedClassName=".bar" syncable="YES">
        ...
    </entity>
    <entity name="FooBar" representedClassName=".fooBar" syncable="YES">
       ...
        <fetchIndex name="fooie">
            <fetchIndexElement property="fooeee" type="Binary" order="ascending"/>
        </fetchIndex>
    </entity>
    <entity name="BarFoo" representedClassName=".barFoo" syncable="YES">
        
        <fetchIndex name="byPropertyIndex">
            <fetchIndexElement property="bla bla bla" type="Binary" order="descending"/>
        </fetchIndex>
    </entity>
    <elements>
        <element name="Foo" positionX="0" positionY="0" width="0" height="0"/>
        <element name="Bar" positionX="0" positionY="0" width="0" height="0"/>
        <element name="FooBar" positionX="0" positionY="0" width="0" height="0"/>
        <element name="BarFoo" positionX="0" positionY="0" width="0" height="0"/>
    </elements>
</model>
```

Any Idea what is going on here? How can I get xcode to open the object Diagram for this model version?

[image]

Comment: You're not using git or similar so you can compare with a previous version? The Digram part is inside the `<elements>` tag and what stands out there is that all values are zero, including height and width. If you don't have an older version to copy from the exact values from then I would try to add some values there and see what happens. As a starter, I looked at an older version of my own model xml file and width was 128 for all elements

Comment: I am using git, and I have tried both reverting the contents in the <elements> xml tags and deleting them. In both cases I am unable to toggle the Editor style. 

I have been able to confirm that these elements are for laying out the "object Diagram" by opening a different version of the scheme, moving the elements around in the GUI, and checking the source file to see the diff.